# Doxygen & Objective-C: wrong nomenclature "Public Member Functions"

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I notice that Doxygen generates documentation that says "Public Member Functions" for Objective-C classes. Objective-C typically talks about methods rather than member functions (C++ nomenclature). I wonder if there is a way to make Doxygen use the correct terminology in its output (short of running the output through sed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the title of the public member section using a custom layout file.

First create the default layout using `doxygen -l`. This creates a file called `DoxygenLayout.xml`

Open the file with a text (or XML) editor and look for `doxygenlayout > class > memberdecl > publicmethods` and edit the title attribute of the element as follows

```
<publicmethods title="Methods"/>
```

Mention your layout file in doxygen's configuration file:

```
LAYOUT_FILE            = DoxygenLayout.xml
```

and run doxygen using this configuration file, and you should see `Methods` as the title of the section instead of `Public Member Functions`.

Comment: Hey, that's really cool. Now which element do I edit to replace "Member Function Documentation" with "Method Documentation" under "Detailed Description"? Are there any other places where the word "functions" shows up?

Comment: Duh, it's the element right under it, 'publicstaticmethods'! Thanks again.